# Is there a way to add all colors used into the swatches panel?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, swatches

Sometimes, when inspiration hits me, I start designing a document using multiple colors. Or I use the Blend tool to create a smooth set of colors for me to work with.

But it always happens that eventually, I need to start matching my colors and keeping better track of them, which I usually do with the Swatches panel.

But I always end up clicking an object/path, dragging the color from the color picker into the swatches panel and then repeating for all the colors I want to keep.

Is there a way for me to just have the Swatches panel add all the current colors in the document or layer or from a selected group?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Select the group of objects you want to grab the colors from and click the `New Color Group` button on the `Swatches` pane. Make sure the `Selected Artwork` option is selected, and you'll get a new color group with all the colors from that selection.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Result]