# How can I get a count of the amount of colors used in an Illustrator document?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I'd like to be able to get a count on the current amount of colors being used in an Illustrator file. Additionally I'd like to be able to export the colors info (names, values, etc.) to a text file if possible.

Does anyone know how to do either of these without counting and exporting each color manually such as this question suggests? [How can I separate colors by layer in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17940/how-can-i-separate-colors-by-layer-in-illustrator)

I've been digging around for an answer and am mostly finding articles on reducing the amount of colors instead of info on providing a count.

Thanks.

Comment: The script I posted [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/71023/52050) should get you at least part of the way

Answer (score 4):

Here's where to find the current color count:

I finally found out where to view the total colors used in Illustrator and wanted to share it in case someone else can use it.

In Illustrator go to Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork. A window like the example below opens up and the current color count is shown below the upper left corner.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make a color group that collects the color from selected artwork. As per  [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13543/is-there-a-way-to-add-all-colors-used-into-the-swatches-panel) post.

Scriptdumping the swatches is easy (in illustrator but not in photoshop for example). But since Cai already [linked one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/71023/52050) lets use it. You can simply alert the length of swatch count.

Answer (score 0):

Select All (Ctrl + A, or CMD + A)

Open Fill in Properties > Appearance

New Colour Group (folder icon)

Check Selected Artwork

Will create a new folder with all the colours inside of it

Comment: .... unless colors are part of a gradient or pattern. Then this method fails.